# How to drop index if another index is available in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have duplicate indexes in my table and want to get rid of the duplicates.

I want to write a script to drop one index from a pair if the other one exists.

Here is my query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE name = 'IX_mDate')
    BEGIN TRY
        DROP INDEX IX_Ma ON MarkTo

        Print 'Dupliate Index has been removed'
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 
       PRINT  error_message()
    END CATCH
```

The problem with this query is that, even if the other duplicate index is not there it goes on to delete the remaining index. How can I achieve what am looking for? Also, is there a way to Drop indexes in one query not one by one?

I am a bit stuck and my client is mourning already. These duplicate indexes are killing performance so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include both indices in the `EXISTS` expression.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Mark') AND name = 'IX_MtmDate')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Mark') AND name = 'IX_Mark')
BEGIN TRY
    DROP INDEX IX_Mark ON Mark

    Print 'Dupliate Index has been removed'
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT  error_message()
END CATCH
```

Comment: the Object_id in the where does not exist in the sysindexes table. How can this work?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the answer. It should be `sys.indexes` not `sysindexes`

Comment: @Cool_Br33zeThanks for your help it's working but the error handling part is not doing anything though. Am trying to fix it but no luck. Any ideas?